# Dynamicaly add images in DIV one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the  i have 9 images , i want to write Jquery code to add only first 3 and last 3 images to  from the selected image .suppose user clicks on 4 then add 1,2,3 to one class and 5,6,7, into another class

how to do this.i tried following but it will add all prev.

```
     t.prevAll().addClass('t1');
     t.nextAll().addClass('t2');
```

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: I really don't see what you want. Can you try to be more precise ?

Comment: Please post your HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:lt` selector:

```
t.nextAll(':lt(3)').addClass('t2');
t.prevAll(':lt(3)').addClass('t1');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvm3T/

Update according to your comment:

If you want to select the 2 first elements, you can use `slice` method:

```
$('#container img').slice(0, 2);
```

Comment: Just change the number `t.prevAll(':lt(2)');`.